# Ubuntu thinks my amd R7 250 is an R9 m360

Tags: 14.04, ati, gpu

I recently installed Ubuntu 14.04 on my newly built computer. My computer has an amd R7 250 GPU, but according to both the system details and amd catalyst I have an R9 m360. Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: Are you sure that you actually have the R7 250? Maybe it's a counterfeit?